# Only read new events from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was halfway done with implementing Core Data in my iOS app when I realized that Firebase has offline capabilities that would pretty much mimic what I was trying to accomplish the whole time.

In my database which is structured as such:

```
- Users
    - user1
    - user2
- Groups
    - group1
        - members
            - user1
        - events
            - event1_By_Auto_Key
            - event2_By_Auto_Key
```

I wanted to locally store all the events that have already been fetched by a user so that I wouldn't have to read all of them every single time I need to get a group's events. Now that I think I'm just going to stick with Firebase's offline capabilities instead of using Core Data, I have a question regarding how to efficiently read events from the database.

As seen from my database's structure the events are stored using the `childByAutoId().setValue(data)` method, meaning the keys are unknown when inserted. So my console for a given group might look like this:

[image: console]

My question is: how can I only read the new events from a group? The reason I was implementing Core Data was so that I could cache already fetched events, but I'm not sure how I can make sure that I don't re-read data.

Comment: Can you clarify why you would want to keep all of the events locally? They are already on in the Firebase database so isn't a local copy a duplicate? It could also lead to local storage issues if there are a lot of events.

Comment: So I don't have to reread data.

Comment: lol. thanks. I got that part. I was asking why you would reread data? i.e. what would cause the app to re-read data? I.e. if this is a series of events, then you probably don't need to read 'old' events so they could be marked as such. Or perhaps there's a date stamp on the event, only read events from today forward. Just curious as it's a little vague as to what *read all of them every single time* means.

Comment: I have a `tableView` that displays all the data. I have to make sure I have the latest events fetched to display them.

Comment: Then when the app starts, load in all events from today until whenever, and attach an observer. Simple as that. From there forward any time the app starts you will have all of the latest events and if any new ones are added, your app will be notified. This is a basic design pattern of Firebase and a very common use case.

Comment: But it's login based and users can be part of multiple groups. I can't just attach an observer because I don't know which groups a user will end up belonging to.

Comment: You can attach an observer at any time and when the user joins a group, attach the observer. OR when the user logs in you will know what groups they belong to so you add them upon login. Likewise, when they leave a group, remove their observer. I would suggest having a node within that users node that keeps track of which groups they belong to so when they log in you can get that and attach observers accordingly.

Comment: If I attach an observer and the user closes the app then later reopens it, will all the events that got added to his groups in the meantime appear right when he reopens the app? I'm confused as to where in the app to attach the observers and when exactly they'll appear.

Comment: Yes. But. You need to have some criteria so your code will know which new ones to show. One option is to simply keep a timestemp in the user node of when they closed the app. Then when they reopen, perform a query for posts for all groups they belong to where the post timestamp startsAt(last_logout). There's a bunch of other options but that's a starting point.

Comment: So when I query for new posts, those will already be cached on the user's phone? Do I need to set `.persistenceEnabled = true` for that to be true?

Comment: You are not querying for new posts. You are using a query to attach an observer which will return posts that meet the query criteria and any future posts that also meet that criteria. You are going to have to experiment with Firebase to get the pattern down, so write some code to do that query to see how it works!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few strategies you could use. Since the ids generated are always lexically greater than any existing, you can use startAt() on your query with the newest record you already have. You just need to skip the record that matches the last ID you have. If you keep a timestamp in the events, you can use orderByChild() and the last timestamp and increment by one ms then you don't get any records you already have. It would be something like:

```
function getNewEvents(group, arrayOfExistingIds) {
  let lastId = arrayOfExistingIds.sort().pop(),
    ref = admin.database().ref('/Groups/' + group + '/events')
      .orderByKey().startAt(lastId).on('value', function(snap){
        if (snap.key === lastId) return;
        console.log('New record: ' + snap.key);
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provide you 10MB persistent memory to cache recently fetch records. In normal scenario 10MB is enough space.

You need to enable offline capabilities.